# Equivalence between gibbs states representations with different temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm asked to answer this question: why two Gibbs states with different temperatures give the same (GNS) representation?
Actually, I can't even imagine if this is true and if not how to find a counter example.

So for a Gibbs state $\rho_{\beta}=Z_{\beta}^{-1}exp(-\beta H)$ where $Z_{\beta}= Tr(exp(- \beta H))$ the GNS representation is construted in this way: $r_0=\rho_{\beta}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. Then take the vector space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $D_0$ and associate the following scalar product: $(X,Y)  = Tr(X^{+}Y)$. $D_0$ is actually a Hilbert space and we denote $r_0$ with the common $|r_0>$. This will be our cyclic vector in GNS representation. Then define a representation in this way: $\pi(A)|r_0> = |A r_0>$. So the triple ($r_0, D_0, \pi$) is the GNS triple for a Gibbs state and the expectation values are written as $\omega_{\beta}(A)=Tr(\rho_{\beta}A)=<r_0|\pi(A)|r_o>$.

Now I must find for two different Gibbs states, respectively with representations $(r_1, D_1, \pi_1)$ and $(r_2,D_2,\pi_2)$ an unitary operator $U:D_1 \to D_2$ such that $\pi_1(A)= U^{+}\pi_2(A)U$.
But at this point I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: It seems to me that the wanted proof of unitary equivalence is easy if you try to realize the GNS representations exploiting  the purification procedure. Later I  will try to sketch a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the fact that $$\rho_\beta :=Z^{-1}_\beta e^{-\beta H}$$ is trace class by definition  in a given (separable) Hilbert space $\cal H$, and thus it can be expanded as:
$$\rho_\beta = \sum_{j\in \mathbb N} p_j(\beta) |\psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j|\quad \mbox{where } 0 \leq p_j(\beta)\leq 1 \mbox{ and} \sum_j p_j(\beta)=1\quad (1)$$
above I use the convention $p_j \leq p_{j+1}$ (where the number of $j$ with a common fixed value $p_j$ is finite because $\rho_\beta$ is compact) and the convergence is in the strong operator topology.

In the considered case, more strongly (it turns out to be important shortly):
$$p_j(\beta)= e^{-\beta E_j}>0 \quad \forall j\:, \forall \beta >0\:.$$

Fix another Hilbert basis $\{\phi_j\}_{j\in \mathbb N} \subset {\cal H}$ and, in ${\cal K}:= {\cal H}\otimes {\cal H}$, define the normalized vector:
$$\Psi_\beta := \sum_{j \in \mathbb N} \sqrt{p_j(\beta)} \psi_j \otimes \phi_j\:.  \quad (2)$$
The triple $\left({\cal K}, \pi, \Psi_\beta \right)$ is a GNS triple for $\rho_\beta$ if:
$$\pi : B({\cal H}) \ni A \mapsto A \otimes I\quad (3)$$

The only thing to be proved, because not self-evident, is that $\{ A\otimes I \Psi_\beta\:|\: A \in B({\cal H})\}$ is dense in $\cal K$.  For every $j$ and $k$, we may pick out $A_{jk} \in B(\cal H)$ such that $A_{jk}\psi_j = \sqrt{\frac{1}{p_j(\beta)}}\psi_k$ (notice that all $p_j$ are strictly positive) and 
$A_{jk}\psi_{j'}=0$ if $j\neq j'$.  Therefore 
$\pi(B(\cal H)) \Psi_\beta$ includes every product $\psi_k \otimes \phi_j$ and thus every linear combinations of these products. Since $\{\psi_k\otimes \phi_j\}_{k,j \in \mathbb N}$ is a Hilbert basis of ${\cal H}\otimes {\cal H}={\cal K}$, we can infer that $\{ A\otimes I \Psi_\beta\:|\: A \in B({\cal H})\}$ is dense in $\cal K$.

To conclude, notice that I never used the value of $\beta$ barring in the definition of $\Psi_\beta$. Consequently, changing $\beta$ we can use the same GNS Hilbert space and GNS representation. Just the identity map is the wanted unitary operator $U : {\cal K} \to {\cal K}$ verifying $U \pi_\beta(A)= \pi_{\beta'}(A)U$.

Comment: Ok so if I take as a simple Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^N$ and take as a ONB base the eigenvalues of the Hamilonian $\{\epsilon_j\}_{j=1,\dots , N}$ the cyclic vector $\psi_{\beta}$ is :

Comment: Working in ${\mathbb C}^N \otimes \mathbb C^N$, it could be $Z_\beta^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^N e^{-\beta E_i/2} e_i \otimes e_i$, but you can replace the $e_i$s in the right entry with any other orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^N$.

Comment: Ok, perfect now the unitary transformation must act such that $U \psi_{\beta_1} = \psi_{\beta_2}$, am I correct?

Comment: No. When one says that two reps ${\cal A} \ni a \mapsto \pi_j(a)$, $j=1,2$ are unitarily equivalent, he/she means that there is a unitary map $U: {\cal H}_1 \to {\cal H}_2$ such that $U \pi_1(a) = \pi_2(a) U$ for all $a\in {\cal A}$. Nothing further. In the considered case ${\cal H}_1={\cal H}_2= {\mathbb C}^N\otimes {\mathbb C}^N$, ${\cal A} = B({\mathbb C}^N)$ and $\pi_1(A)= \pi_2(A) = A \otimes I$. So $U=I$. The reps are equivalent but the states are *different*, obviously.

Comment: I see, you are requiring a much stronger thing. But it is false, the states are different if $\beta$ is different, physics must be different! In general my weaker requirement is false, comparing the GNS reps of two states. The simplest case is when you compare the GNS rep of a pure state with that of a mixed state: There is no operator $U$ as I wrote (independently from the action on the cyclic vectors).

Comment: Ok, understood.. Now if I consider a system whit infintely DoF, things go in different way. The next step is to prove that KMS states with different temperatures give inequivalent representations.

Comment: The fact that your operator $U$ cannot exist for different values of $\beta$ is the following. Adopt a pure algebraic framework, the two states are $\omega_\beta$ and $\omega_{\beta'}$ over that same abstract $C^*$-algebra ${\cal A}$. If a unitary operator satisfying all requirements (mine and yours), you easily see, passing through the GNS representations that $\omega_\beta(a) =...= \omega_{\beta'}(a)$ for all $a\in {\cal A}$. This is physically false, but it is false also mathematically as it would imply $\omega_\beta= \omega_{\beta'}$.

Comment: when you say infinitely DoF do you mean infinitely extended systems? (I.e. fields). In that case things become more complicated. I suggest you: Haag's textbook, Bratteli-Robinson's textbook, a pair of book by Sewell.